# Publish an application problem

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I Publish software successfull using GPO policy but when user log on and try to install that software from add/remove program, there is one message popup saying that user should have administrative privillages and it is stopping installation.

Could any one can solve this.
thanks

Comment: This sounds like it's working as it should? Are the users in the local Administrators group?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the application to install with administrative privileges, it needs to be linked into the computer section of the GPO and then applied to the computer. If its linked into the user portion of the GPO, it will install in the users context and if that user isn't a local admin or power user, it will fail.